# Arduino consuming lots of data from firebase

Tags: firebase, arduino, firebase-authentication, arduino-esp8266

I am working on Arduino-firebase home automation project.
Now, Firebase data changed through mobile application and Arduino Esp8266 model reads data from firebase. So every time in loop it calls

```
 FirebaseObject firebaseObject=Firebase.get(path_command);
```

and it consumes data  continuously .
So here is my question, **Is there any way to get data only when it is changed on firebase server?.**

I have tried below code, but it crashes device at

**if (Firebase.available())**

```
Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH);
  Firebase.stream("/devices/_18_fe_34_d6_9_4f_/command");
if (Firebase.failed()) {
    Serial.println("streaming error");
    Serial.println(Firebase.error());
  }

  if (Firebase.available()) {
      FirebaseObject firebaseObject = Firebase.readEvent();     
      String deviceToken=firebaseObject.getString("device_token");   
        Serial.println(deviceToken);    
  }
```

Please guide me if better solution available, Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

We have found the solution for the heavy Data usage.
Previously we were getting all json array using below code.

```
 FirebaseObject firebaseObject=Firebase.get(path_command);
```

Which consumes several byte or Kb data.
while now we are checking it first that is any change made in data by extra flag
Version. and it is incremental.
We have store it in our database for each node level and each time data updates we need to change it by incrementing  it.
Now we need to check version before getting all json array as below way

```
   int version =Firebase.getInt(version_path);
       if(version!=previosVersion)
              FirebaseObject firebaseObject=Firebase.get(path_command);
```

. if we are getting version   difference then only we need to get json object.
Before that in an hour Arduino was consuming around 3 to 5 MB per hour and now it is consuming 700-800 KB per hour. still we are look for best optimization.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function `Firebase.available()` which returns a boolean value (true or false).
If it returns true, meaning that some sort of data change occurred in the database, so you can retrieve it.

But this function becomes valid only if you call the above function after this function:

```
Firebase.stream("path u wish to monitor changes");
```

For more information, read the documentation for [Firebase.available()](http://firebase-arduino.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#_CPPv2N15FirebaseArduino6streamERK6String)